# Angular 7: Misunderstanding how router Link imports

Tags: angular, angular7

I am new to Angular and am following https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=1223&v=5wtnKulcquA tutorial.

I know I'm trying to run before crawling, but I cannot seem to figure out how the routerLink imports works. According to the ng serve testing, my import declarations is correct and I believe the problem is that I am missing the knowledge on the routing paths or actual routing linking. I've tried to manipulating the paths but nothing works.

Can someone explain to me what am I missing?

My directory structure is:

```
app
    launcher
        header
        content (where routerOutlet is located)
            welcome
            about
            projects
            client
            contact
        footer
    portal
       ...

My navigation links in the header folder:
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <a routerLink="/" class="logo">{{pageTitle}}</a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a routerLink="/">Home</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/about">About</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/projects">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/client">Client</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="/contact">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

Within my app-routing.module.ts:

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { WelcomeComponent } from './launcher/content/welcome/welcome.component';
    import { AboutComponent } from './launcher/content/about/about.component';
    import { ProjectsComponent } from './launcher/content/projects/projects.component';
    import { ClientComponent } from './launcher/content/client/client.component';
    import { ContactComponent } from './launcher/content/contact/contact.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path:'', component: WelcomeComponent },
  { path:'', component: AboutComponent },
  { path:'', component: ProjectsComponent },
  { path:'', component: ClientComponent },
  { path:'', component: ContactComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: your path property is always empty. Every path normally corresponds to the desired url

Comment: Try starting with the official documentation/tutorial on [Routing & Navigation](https://angular.io/guide/router) first. It explains really well how routes/paths and links work including nested routes as well as how `NgModule` relates.

Comment: For example: `/projects` correspond to path 'projects' so you need to set `{ path:'projects', component: ProjectsComponent }`

Comment: Solved. Thank you. Question, how do I close this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I was trying to follow the video and missed when the instructor entered the path specifications. Filled and fixed. Thank you.